# Do I need to use "guess" or "try to guess" when I want someone to try to anwer my question?

Tags: phrase-choice

Does the following sentences mean the same?

> If you don't know the answer, **guess** it.
>
> If you don't know the answer, **try to guess** it.

By the way, do I have to inclide *it* after *guess*?

Comment: I’d say “guess” or “make a guess” or “take a guess”, no “it”.

Answer (score 2):

As soon often, Google Books Ngram Viewer gives an excellent insight into popular usage.

**Guess** is the runaway winner. 
It is many times more popular than the other two options.

**Guess it** makes a weak showing.

**Try to guess it** barely features at all.

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=guess%2Cguess+it%2Ctry+to+guess+it&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&

Answer (score 2):

Both sentences mean the same. A US English speaker would probably not include "it" but it is not incorrect to include it.